Expression -(a*b) and other superfluous parentheses in OutputForm
Mathematica sometimes places parentheses where technically none are needed, especially siding an unary minus sign. Some I would condone: a^(-b). Some look silly: -(a*b)-c*d. Is my assuption correct that Mathematica places superfluous parentheses only and always around unary minus signs? (Since the second minus in my second example is a "normal" minus sign, it gets no parenthesis.) If yes, maybe this can even be switched off...
I am using WolframScript, so the same behaviour can be replicated with OutputForm:
-a*b - c*d // OutputForm
(* -(a b) - c d *)

Related question

Can you please show us the code where these parentheses are produced? If I evaluate -a*b - c*d, I get back the same form, without any parentheses.

Similarly -(a*b)-c*d and (-a)*b - c*d for that matter evaluate to -a*b-c*d, because Times is Flat.

@Domen: I did it in WolframScript, could that be the difference? I simply entered -a*b-c*d and it came out as -(a*b)-c*d (as prompt and in InputForm). TraditionalForm drops the parentheses.

Ah, yes, that's an important piece of information, because in WolframScript, the default format is OutputFormat. I have slightly edited your question to emphasize this.

Actually both InputForm and OutputForm add (). Screen shot https://i.sstatic.net/olUGWsA4.png But internally (i.e. FullForm) there is ofcourse no ()  which is Plus[Times[-1,a,b],Times[-1,c,d]]  Mathematica uses the FullForm

StandardForm[...] or TraditionalForm[...] will convert -(ab)-cd  to the form without superfluous parentheses.
